# python pyautogui.dragRel not effect(drag window)

Tags: python

I try to use the function `pyautogui.dragRel` to chrome(browser) Title, but there is no effect(drag window).

What should I do?

Below have gif picture, this is the effect I want:

[image: 1]

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.mouseDown(1000,10)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.dragRel(10,500)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add mor detail about what you are doing? like what you want to do, what is the output or if you had some tracebacks?

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Hi, this pyautogui.dragRel function effect drag, so i think about drag windown for my web, i have add gif picture for example, thanks!.

Comment: I suggest you to modify the tags according to the topic to get more atttenction

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Hi, do you have idea give me reference, thank you so much!

Comment: I would add pyautogui tag of course and other tags linket to what you are working with, and maybe i'll post a bigger piece of code to show where this snippet comes and when is it used

Comment: Hello I have the exact same problem and can't find the solution.... To add details missing in OP's question: the window is not moving as I can do with my hands, when the code snippet is run

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the solution is pretty simple but not easy to find. I find the actual writing of this in:

[Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, 2nd Edition: Practical Programming](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RQ6xDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA479&lpg=PA479&dq=windows%20not%20dragged%20by%20pyautogui&source=bl&ots=fccTPG8VvH&sig=ACfU3U1wzr1OlukAtviOQT2vlASHHYpjLw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifhfONsZ30AhXCzIUKHTPuC8AQ6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=windows%20not%20dragged%20by%20pyautogui&f=false)
Of Al Sweigart

The solution is to add a duration to the action of dragging, because some windows won't react to a fast move (maybe some sort of security in the code, to avoid mouse bugs).

```
pyautogui.dragTo(410, 330, duration=0.2)
```